# plot background lines in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot line chart from pandas dataframe, but as shown in the image below I aim to plot different colors in the background of the chart.

Here is how I plotted line chart.

```
ax = df.plot(kind='line')
plt.legend(ncol=6, bbox_to_anchor=(1.04,1))
plt.savefig("output.png", bbox_inches="tight")
plt.show()
```

[image: Graph]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `axhspan` and/or `axvspan`

Here is a small example that may help you

```
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    plt.figure()
    plt.xlim(0, 5)
    plt.ylim(0, 5)
    
    for i in range(0, 5):
        plt.axhspan(i, i+.2, facecolor='0.2', alpha=0.5)
        plt.axvspan(i, i+.5, facecolor='b', alpha=0.5)
    
    plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `fill_between()`

```
plt.figure()
x = range(10)
c = ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'yellow', 'teal']
y = [0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15]
for i in range(5):
    plt.fill_between(x, y1 = y[i+1], y2 = y[i], facecolor = c[i], alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]

Comment: i have used fill_between but it gives bars only on specific area not behind whole graph, see https://imgur.com/8RAjXh7

Comment: fill_between function fills the area between the curves y1 and y2. Consider checking the y values and make sure the facecolor is not white